# Structure in C - Access value

Tags: c

I am trying to play around with structure and this is what I have:

```
  #DEFINE LINEAR 1
  int val;
  struct Item
  {
      double price;
      int weight;
      char Tax;
      int quant;
      int minQuant;
      char namel[30];  
  };

  double totalAfterTax(struct Item item);

 int main() {
   struct Item I[21] = 
   {
     { 4.4,275,8,10,2,"Royal Apples" },
     { 5.99,386,18,20,4,"Melon"},
   };
   val = display(I[0], LINEAR);
   return 0;
 } //main end


   void display(struct Item item, int linear){

   struct Item i1; 
   printf ("%d ", i1.quant); 
   return;
   }
```

Now, problem is i1.quant is not printing 8 as it is supposed to. I am not sure why?

Please advise?

Comment: You are printing `i1` instead of `item`. `i1` is an uninitialised variable.

Comment: You need to assign a struct to `i1`, i.e., `i1` is uninitialized.

Comment: Wait a second ... In your `void display` function, why are you doing `printf( "%d ", i1.quant);` instead of `printf( "%d ", item.quant);`??

Comment: btw you should expect quant to be 10 with your current data,  as it is the 4th field.

Comment: Also, `val = display(I[0], LINEAR);` .. `display` is `void` .. does this compile and what do you expect the value of `val` to be?

Comment: Thanks @all. I get it now.

Comment: @txtechhelp You are right. I should make it as int and return an integer

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `display` function, you define an 'empty' (uninitialized) `struct Item`. I believe what you wanted to print should be `item.quant`:

```
void display(struct Item item, int linear){
    printf ("%d ", item.quant); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the line below should be removed

```
struct Item i1;
```

and you should replace printing line with the following:

```
printf ("%d \n",item.quant);
```

According to your program it should give you an error or warning and after making above changes, output should be "10" not 8. As you are printing `item.quant`.